# Associate two models through foreign key in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have two models in my rails app: `report.rb` and `user.rb`

**Reports table**

```
id
assigned_user_id
amount
costs
etc.
```

**Users table**

```
id
assigned_user_id
email
prename
etc.
```

I know how I could associate both models with belongs_to and has_many if I use standard Rails logic (having a user_id on the reports table etc.).

But since I don't have a `user_id` on the reports table, I would like to connect both tables through `assigned_user_id` but I don't know now how to specify my association in my models.

Answer (score 1):

To alias a 1-to-many association use the `foreign_key` and `class_name` options.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # without foreign_key Rails would look for the inverse 
  # in reports.user_id
  has_many :reports, foreign_key: :assigned_user_id
end

class Report < ApplicationRecord
  # class_name is needed since the class name cannot be deduced by
  # the name of the association
  belongs_to :assigned_user, class_name: 'User'
end
```

Comment: hm ok. did this but if i now create an instance variable with all reports, iterate through it (<% @all_reports.each do |report| %>) and do report.user.prename for example it throws me the error "undefined method `user' for #<Report:0x007fb3b87274c8>"